# split string with having dot as deliminator and dot in value as well

Tags: c#

I have below different string value,

Format is,

**"Some string"**.**"some string"**.**"the content which I'm interested to capture(it may contain dot)"**.**"option some string"**

```
var str1 = "XXX.XXX.test.com.X1";
var str2 = "Y.YY.google.co.in.X2";
var str3 = "ZZ.ZZZ.google.co.in";
var str4 = "PPPP.P.Yahoo";
```

where I'm interested to capture,

**test.com** from str1

**google.co.in** from str2

**google.co.in** from str3

**Yahoo** from str4

I tried below,

```
var str4 = "PPPP.P.Yahoo";
        var part = str4.Split(new char[] { '.' }, 4);
        var result = part[2];
```

It will give correct result only for `str4` as we have dot in between (`test.com`, etc) for other.

What could be elegant way to split it?

Comment: Can you add some explanation of the logic that dictates you should get test.com, google.co.in, and Yahoo? Why should you get google.co.in and not PPP.P.Yahoo? How are they different?

Comment: Regex alone can't really do this; we would need to probably maintain a whitelist of domain names, and also the domain extension types which you are expecting.

Comment: Jonn, the format is "Some string"**.**"some string"**.**"the content which I'm interested to capture(it may contain dot)"**.**"option some string"

Comment: OK, and is the problem that "some string"."some string" contains dots too? How do you, as a human, differentiate? How do you know it's "google.co.in" for `str3` and not "google.co" with "in" as an "option string"?

Comment: "some string"."some string" will never have any dot

Comment: OK, so how do you, as a human, know that it's "google.co.in" and not "google.co" with option string "in"?

Comment: that string may have one or more dot, google i just took as example, the ""option some string" will also not contain dot

Comment: OK, if you had aa.bb.foo.bar.zz, how do you know if you want "foo.bar.zz" or "foo.bar" with option "zz" (as a human)? I'm focusing on the google example for its periods, not that it's Google.

Comment: @user584018 I don't know maybe there is some language barrier or something, but you need to understand strings `"XXX.XXX.test.com.X1"` and `"ZZ.ZZZ.google.co.in"` are identical, why did you chose from the first one only `"test.com"`, but for the second one `"google.co.in"`?

Comment: Any unique pattern is there? Here @John is right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this might be you get some help.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var str1 = "XXX.XXX.test.com.X1";
    var str2 = "Y.YY.google.co.in.X2";
    var str3 = "ZZ.ZZZ.google.co.in";
    var str4 = "PPPP.P.Yahoo";
    var str5="XX.XXX.test.com.Y1";
    var str6="Y.YY.google.co.in.X2";
    var str7 ="Y.YY.google.co.in.XX";

    var regex = new Regex(@".[XY][0-9a-zA-Z](.*)", RegexOptions.Singleline);

    str1=string.Join(".", str1.Split('.').Skip(2).ToArray());
    str2=string.Join(".", str2.Split('.').Skip(2).ToArray());
    str3=string.Join(".", str3.Split('.').Skip(2).ToArray());
    str4=string.Join(".", str4.Split('.').Skip(2).ToArray());
    str5=string.Join(".", str5.Split('.').Skip(2).ToArray());
    str6=string.Join(".", str6.Split('.').Skip(2).ToArray());
    str7=string.Join(".", str7.Split('.').Skip(2).ToArray());

     Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(str1, ""));
     Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(str2, ""));
     Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(str3, ""));
     Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(str4, ""));
     Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(str5, ""));
     Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(str6, ""));
     Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(str7, ""));
}
```

See this [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/psWjYq) as well

```
Output like below:

test.com
google.co.in
google.co.in
Yahoo
test.com
google.co.in
google.co.in
```

Comment: @user Note that the `regex.Replace(` part simply removes the end part where it matches the form X followed by a digit. This won't work for `XX.XXX.test.com.Y1`, for example. It will output `test.com.Y1`. Is this what you intended?

Comment: @user584018 Even if `"Y.YY.google.co.in.X2"` will be `"Y.YY.google.co.in.XX"`, it will output `"google.co.in.XX"`.

Comment: Check my edited answer and also check demo link